# How can I save Prosys Simulation Server Data to MySQL Database using Node-RED?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, node-red, opc-ua

I have a simulation server (Prosys Simulation Server) and I want to save the data in MySQL database. I have already setup a local database. 
I am using Node-RED for this task because node-red can be connected with Prosys Simulation Server and with MySQL database as well.
The problem I am facing is the inter-connection between the OPC UA client node and MySQL node. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem and posted it in the node-red forum. Here's [the link](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-can-i-save-prosys-simulation-server-data-to-mysql-database-using-node-red/14135).

This is the screenshot of the flow:
[image]

This is the text in the template node:

```
INSERT INTO test.prosys_table(Counter, Time) VALUES ('{{payload}}',Now());
```